# "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" error when using Live HTTP headers

Tags: firefox

"In Firefox, when I use live HTTP header, I see this strange message:

https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom

```
GET /mail/feed/atom HTTP/1.1
Host: mail.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PREF=ID=5d88c373c5a7729c:U=0d6459f22cf0928f:FF=4:LD=en:CR=2:TM=1307949760:LM=1313474617:GM=1:S=n0OyfeoPnxcTwzL6; NID=53=TSK9FerIJdD_eSm5lXAf5CnKsMed5ALsv-yQrHLgLc_2Uh4RNdOYikBs7FklnuY53NO1gudoOoQEx08wuGw4BweQ-lYQyhBqSstwmTAw2_UKeqtoNceSxvEX5p7jg8df; SID=DQAAAL0AAAA172MRtdiGyomwlld1kQQgDCp3FAQA5sUjJZ9ySY_CX2uwaxpHL-OBM5UiHKlsveUa8l5FM3RRfUrYj2EQmyNuREKYZFHwuUrD27IwgiFeZmjCKX7itmKAblawsPzAqfD156paSSLa_r2ZWILR9yXUS_TkAAnXKZtR7LiQ2-avhRqhXzMWQpB5v4aB4aXiZ3_OSf6mOc04PaCxfGbDqG7t-izFjVKsBpNJ7zHbCrzw9mVp9B40v9KgTh3-rExt3Lk; HSID=AvnQnllEln1I2S_AE; SSID=AxSc67XEN4uKqrY03; APISID=yExMEnVMIE5mm8Fc/AuGt1svbDRcoa6Ag8; SAPISID=ac6WdwnI1S5VNJ_8/AwZI6nJda8AEGl952

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="New mail feed"
Content-Length: 147
Date: Sat, 19 Nov 2011 13:34:35 GMT
Expires: Sat, 19 Nov 2011 13:34:35 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
```

Again and again and again and again. How do I turn that off? What does Firefox try to do anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail allows accessing your inbox as an Atom feed using a newsreader. It's possible that you have added this feed to Firefox as a "Live Bookmark". Search all your bookmarks.

Comment: I couldn't find it. Nor am I logged in to gmail.

Comment: I check this one out anyway. Still not solving the problem though.

Comment: Do not accept answers that you think are incorrect, @Jim.